# OpenCV detect corners

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm using OpenCV on the iPhone. I want to find a Sudoku in a photo.
I started with some Gaussian Blur, Adaptive Threshold, Inverting the image and Dilate.
Then I did some findContour and drawContour to isolate the Sudoku grid.
Then I've used the Hough Transform to find lines and what I need to do now is find the corners of the grid. The Sudoku photo may be taken in an angle so I need to find the corners so I can crop and warp the image correctly.

This is how two different photos may look. One is pretty straight and one in an angle:

Probabilistic Hough

http://img96.imageshack.us/i/skrmavbild20110424kl101.png/

http://img846.imageshack.us/i/skrmavbild20110424kl101.png/

(Standard Hough comes in a comment. I can't post more than two links)

So, what would be the best approach to find those corners? And which of the two transform is easiest to use?

Best Regards
Linus

Comment: Standard Hough:

http://img269.imageshack.us/i/skrmavbild20110424kl101.png/

http://img808.imageshack.us/i/skrmavbild20110424kl101.png/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use OpenCV's corner detection?  Take a look at cvCornerHarris().

Alternatively, take a look at cvGoodFeaturesToTrack().  It's the Swiss Army Knife of feature detection and can be configured to use the Harris corner detector (among others).

Comment: Corner detector will also find corners on digits lying inside cells

Comment: I used cvGoodFeaturesToTrack() instead. Now I have X and Y values for all four (sometimes it finds more) corners. Now I need to figure out which point is the topLeft, topRight and so on. Any ideas how I can do that? It seems to just iterate all the points and check the values but I fail when the image is not straight... Ideas?

Comment: Check out /samples/c/squares.c in your OpenCV distribution.  This example provides a square detector, and it should be a pretty good start.  It's likely that you will have to extend it some to detect the parallelograms that result from viewing a square under rotation.

Comment: Thank you @Throwback1986. I will check it out. There is no function that does the same as cvBoundingRect() that also handles rotated rectangles/squares? Possible to use Moments to find the angle of the rectangle and then rotate the image? Then I could use the boundingRect function which would be aweseome :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach. First, find all intersections of lines. It is helpful to sepparate lines into "horisontal" and "vertical" by angle (i.e. find two major directions of lines). Then find the convex hull of acquired points. Now you have corners and some points on the boundaries. You can remove the latter by analysing the angle between neighbour points in the convex hull. Corners will have the angle about 90 degrees and points on the boundaries - about 180 degrees.